# will Location Summary for "Always Allow" location permission shown for iBeaconRegion Monitoring as well in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ibeacon, clregion

From iOS 13, location permissions are tricky to get "Always Allow" from the user. Till if we managed to get the permission and if we are integrated locationUpdate callbacks, Users will get the below location permission reminder form os with tracked location coordinates. This is happening for GeoFencing a region in CoreLocation.

***Will the reminder prompt be shown to the user even if we do Beacon based location monitoring in iOS?***(With the blue dots, similar to geofencing).

Basically, will the blue dots be shown for coordinates tracking? or beacon-based tracking/app wake-up as well?

Thanks in Advance,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Starting with iOS 13, the operating system will periodically show a warning dialog to the user with a map plotting the locations where the app obtained a CoreLocation callback in the background.  **This happens even for apps that only use CoreLocation beacon APIs** even if they do not access latitude and longitude.

This can be alarming to the user and potentially misleading, because for many beacon use cases the app has no idea of the user’s geographic location.

See my full blog post on the subject here:  http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2019/10/18/permission-denied

Comment: your blog is very useful. At least, is it possible to reduce the blue dots count when using beacon API?

 In my case, it is showing more blue dots alone wherever the user travelled. I am not even getting lat & long and that alert with those dots are very scary even for me :)

Comment: You might try changing the way that you use location APIs to reduce the number of updates you get.  I am not certain precisely how iOS records the data points for plotting on the map.  For example, if you are **ONLY** monitoring CLBeaconRegion entry/exit events, do you get a point plotted on the map at the current known lat/long when you enter the region and then again when you exit the region?  (You might also get another point plotted if you call [locationManager.requestState(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423804-requeststate)). Test and see.

Comment: It may also be that iOS brutally plots a point at every location update recorded by the OS over time your app has background location updates of any kind enabled, even if you get no callbacks.  Again, you'd have to test to confirm.